# proguard not obfuscating bean creation in xml

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

Am trying to obfuscate my spring project, class files are obfuscated properly, but not bean definition in xml files.

```
package com.stack.request;
public class Employee(){ 
  String name;
  String age;
}
```

obfuscated to

```
package a.b.a;
public class a(){
  String a;
  String b;
}
```

but bean in xml is like this

```
<bean id="employee" class="com.stack.request.Employee"></bean>
```

will it obfuscate to

```
<bean id="employee" class="a.b.a.a"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but i doubt proguard will do it, proguard analyses your byte code and obfuscate them.

It is framework agnostic, every framework might have it's own requirement.

I would suggest to use annotations instead of xml and use qualifier annotations with your beans.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm